# Asus ul80vt hybrid graphics - how to disable the Intel GPU?

Tags: graphics, asus, hybrid

I'm running ubuntu 13.04. I have an asus ul80vt. There is an integrated intel gpu and an nvidia geforce g210m. I want to disable the intel gpu and just use the nvidia. I have found one helpful source at [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=120903). But this method involves the directory at /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch. I do not have this directory and I have looked as root and checked hidden files, vgaswitcheroo isn't present in /sys/kernel/debug. I'm not really sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 0):

This link would help you to use your nVidia GPU.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee#Installation

Comment: I'm wondering if it was helpful for you?